# Rails server doesn't respond

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.7 on a Windows 7 machine - tried going through an upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2 over the weekend, but ran into issues, so have since gone back to 1.8.7. After restoring my app and re-installing all of the gems, the application finally launches with rails s:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-08-15 14:05:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-08-15 14:05:28] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
[2011-08-15 14:05:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3692 port=3000
```

but I cannot access the site. The browsers just sit there "Waiting for localhost..." and there's absolutely no output from rails. I'm at a loss at how to even investigate this or what might be causing the problem? As far as I can tell MySQL is up and running. In fact, I'm even able to successfully launch and use the console via 'rails console', but WEBrick refuses to deliver me any pages. Are there any logs out there I should be looking at? Or does anyone know what could be causing behavior like this?

The only errors I do get are when I shut down the server, so I can't tell if they are relevant, but here's what I receive:

```
`[2011-08-15 13:59:24] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in`write'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in`<<'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in`_write_data'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:180:in`send_header'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:103:in`send_response'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:79:in `run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
        script/rails:6:in `require'
        script/rails:6
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `shutdown' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:17:in `shutdown'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:211:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:113:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:113:in `join'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:113:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:113:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:113:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6`
```

Can't find anything else to even investigate. Only thing that possibly concerns me is that I did do a Windows Update and picked up a dozen or two new Windows patches in the process of doing the [attempted] upgrade over the weekend, have a hard time imagining those would cause this?

Other Environment Information (as far as I can tell, none of it has changed since before upgrade):

```
D:\dev\src\soletron\Sites\soletronspree>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Users/aslepak/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

D:\dev\src\soletron\Sites\soletronspree>rails -v
Rails 3.0.7

D:\dev\src\soletron\Sites\soletronspree>bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * abstract (1.0.0)
  * actionmailer (3.0.7)
  * actionpack (3.0.7)
  * activemerchant (1.14.0)
  * activemodel (3.0.7)
  * activerecord (3.0.7)
  * activeresource (3.0.7)
  * activesupport (3.0.7)
  * acts_as_list (0.1.2)
  * addressable (2.2.6)
  * arel (2.0.10)
  * aws-s3 (0.6.2)
  * bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
  * braintree (2.10.2)
  * builder (2.1.2)
  * bundler (1.0.17)
  * cancan (1.6.4)
  * crack (0.1.8)
  * deface (0.5.2a 21574e8)
  * devise (1.3.3)
  * erubis (2.6.6)
  * evernote (1.1.0)
  * faker (0.9.5)
  * faraday (0.6.1)
  * fgraph (0.6.1)
  * heroku (2.4.1)
  * highline (1.5.1)
  * httparty (0.7.8)
  * i18n (0.5.0)
  * jquery-rails (0.2.6)
  * koala (1.1.0)
  * launchy (2.0.5)
  * mail (2.2.19)
  * meta_search (1.0.5)
  * mime-types (1.16)
  * multi_json (1.0.3)
  * multi_xml (0.2.2)
  * multipart-post (1.1.3)
  * mysql2 (0.2.6)
  * nested_set (1.6.4)
  * nokogiri (1.5.0)
  * oa-core (0.2.6)
  * oa-oauth (0.2.6)
  * oauth (0.4.5)
  * oauth2 (0.4.1)
  * orm_adapter (0.0.5)
  * paperclip (2.3.8)
  * polyglot (0.3.2)
  * rack (1.2.3)
  * rack-mount (0.6.14)
  * rack-test (0.5.7)
  * rails (3.0.7)
  * railties (3.0.7)
  * rake (0.9.2)
  * rd_find_by_param (0.1.1)
  * rd_resource_controller (1.0.1)
  * rd_unobtrusive_date_picker (0.1.0)
  * rest-client (1.6.3)
  * sequel (3.20.0)
  * sinatra (1.0)
  * spree (0.60.0)
  * spree_api (0.60.0)
  * spree_auth (0.60.0)
  * spree_core (0.60.0)
  * spree_dash (0.60.0)
  * spree_heroku (1.1.0 0471de9)
  * spree_promo (0.60.0)
  * spree_sample (0.60.0)
  * spree_social (1.1)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.4)
  * sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
  * state_machine (0.9.4)
  * stringex (1.0.3)
  * taps (0.3.23)
  * term-ansicolor (1.0.6)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * thrift (0.6.0)
  * thrift_client (0.6.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.29)
  * warden (1.0.5)
  * will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
  * xml-simple (1.1.0)
```

Comment: turns out it was a mysql2 problem after all - v0.2.6 doesn't work on Windows. Upgrading to 0.2.11 made everything work again...

Comment: Are you able to post that as an answer instead of leaving it as a comment?